# How to listen to changes in user authentication verification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to listen for changes to the isEmailVerified boolean and perform an action as soon as the user verifies their email.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener {
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            val emailVerified = user!!.isEmailVerified
        }
```